# Using Button to display dynamic graphics

Tags: dynamic

I have a `DynamicModule` with several graphic elements. I would like to create a button which would change a parameter and re-run the entire module.

Say that we have

```
h := Plot[Sin[k*x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

with an initial value of `k = 1`.

I want to create `Button["Increase k", k = k + 1; h]` that would run the plot (without using `Print[h]` as `h` is really a large `DynamicModule`).

Comment: Actually to get rid of creation of buttons `Manipulate` is used. As sample add one more parameter(g) to it `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[k*x + g], {x, 0, 10}], {k, 1, 10}, {g, 1, 10}]` controls for k ,g are created automatically.

Comment: If h is really huge I advise You to not put it all inside `Dynamic`. Add `Dynamic` only to `k` wherever it is (pay attention to Heads) or in case of `Manipulate` include only that `Button` and maybe append `TrackedSymbols:>{ k, ...}`.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an addendum to jVincent's answer.

I do this sort of thing all the time when a full-bore `Manipulate` would be overkill. I recommend adding a `Reset` button and a dynamic label to make the dynamic behavior more `Manipulate`-like.

```
h := Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, N[4 Pi]},
  PlotLabel -> Sin[k x],
  ImageSize -> Medium];
btns = Row[{Button["k++", k++], Button["Reset", k = 1]}, Spacer[10]];
k = 1; Column[{Dynamic@h, btns}]
```

[image: DynamicPlot]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply display `h` in a `Dynamic` and then create your button to increase `k`, so first define your module:

```
k = 1;
h := Plot[Sin[k*x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Then display the plot and button:

```
Button["Increase k", k = k + 1]
Dynamic[h]
```